# BoundingBox dataclass implementation with cupy, cudf, and nvector

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pandas, cuda

The dataset I'm working with is rather large so I've been experimenting with `cudf` and `cupy`. [Here](https://rapids.ai/start.html#get-rapids) you can find instructions for installing `cudf` and `cupy`.  You will need a capable GPU and the nvidia drivers.  Below I have provided a `small` portion of the data and an example of how to mimic the `gpu_session` `function`.  Their apis are pretty similar to `numpy` and `pandas` so it wouldn't be too much to just replace the gpu module imports and run it on the cpu.

okay, sample data...

### columns

```
columns = ['MUCAPE', 'MLCAPE', 'MLCIN', 'EBSHEAR', 'SRH01KM', 'MEANWIND_1-3kmAGL','MESH', 'VIL_DENSITY', 'FLASH_RATE', 'FLASH_DENSITY', 'MAXLLAZ','P98LLAZ', 'P98MLAZ', 'WETBULB_0C_HGT', 'PWAT', 'CAPE_M10M30', 'LJA','SIZE', 'MOTION_EAST', 'MOTION_SOUTH', 'PS', 'ID', 'VALIDTIME', 'MINX','MINY', 'MAXX', 'MAXY', 'X', 'Y']
```

### data

```
data = [[2066, 1657, -1, 42.099998474121094, 284, 39.099998474121094, 0.28999999165534973, 1.940000057220459, 7, 0.25999999046325684, 0.003000000026077032, 0.0020000000949949026, 0.0020000000949949026, 9.899999618530273, 1.5, 447, 0.0, 59, 4.497000217437744, 5.374000072479248, 26, 111651, '2022-04-16 08:30:35', -89.62000274658203, 34.20000076293945, -89.55000305175781, 34.27000045776367, -89.58499908447266, 34.23062515258789], [1078, 285, -38, 37.900001525878906, 123, 23.600000381469727, 0.029999999329447746, 0.8799999952316284, 0, 0.0, 0.004000000189989805, 0.0020000000949949026, 0.0020000000949949026, 11.199999809265137, 1.600000023841858, 188, 0.0, 253, 6.75, -0.9750000238418579, 3, 113455, '2022-04-16 14:24:40', -84.0, 32.040000915527344, -83.77999877929688, 32.22999954223633, -83.92500305175781, 32.144386291503906], [678, 251, -160, 48.29999923706055, 87, 18.5, 0.05999999865889549, 0.949999988079071, 1, 0.05999999865889549, 0.003000000026077032, 0.0020000000949949026, 0.003000000026077032, 11.600000381469727, 1.399999976158142, 74, 0.0, 308, 8.975000381469727, 5.38100004196167, 6, 112748, '2022-04-16 11:46:37', -85.44000244140625, 31.100000381469727, -85.13999938964844, 31.280000686645508, -85.23500061035156, 31.192279815673828], [27, 0, 0, 8.399999618530273, 212, 33.099998474121094, 0.0, 0.38999998569488525, 0, 0.0, 0.0010000000474974513, 0.0, 0.0010000000474974513, 4.599999904632568, 0.8999999761581421, 0, 0.0, 139, 10.62399959564209, 2.4179999828338623, 0, 112144, '2022-04-16 09:38:38', -82.93000030517578, 36.689998626708984, -82.77999877929688, 36.790000915527344, -82.8550033569336, 36.73691177368164], [206, 0, 0, 21.5, 343, 37.099998474121094, 0.0, 0.6499999761581421, 1, 0.05999999865889549, 0.006000000052154064, 0.004999999888241291, 0.004000000189989805, 7.0, 1.0, 31, 0.0, 642, 14.494000434875488, -2.197999954223633, 0, 110971, '2022-04-16 05:52:39', -86.05999755859375, 35.150001525878906, -85.72000122070312, 35.5099983215332, -85.8949966430664, 35.336753845214844], [202, 0, 0, 27.399999618530273, 305, 40.099998474121094, 0.0, 0.41999998688697815, 0, 0.0, 0.003000000026077032, 0.003000000026077032, 0.003000000026077032, 8.899999618530273, 1.2000000476837158, 32, 0.0, 69, 15.645000457763672, -3.1070001125335693, 1, 111160, '2022-04-16 06:40:39', -86.58000183105469, 36.130001068115234, -86.47000122070312, 36.209999084472656, -86.54499816894531, 36.176849365234375], [1717, 1034, -34, 44.79999923706055, 78, 17.5, 0.5199999809265137, 1.809999942779541, 16, 0.6200000047683716, 0.010999999940395355, 0.007000000216066837, 0.004000000189989805, 10.199999809265137, 1.7000000476837158, 345, 1.5, 260, 8.045000076293945, 3.00600004196167, 32, 113168, '2022-04-16 13:30:37', -93.81999969482422, 34.61000061035156, -93.62999725341797, 34.84000015258789, -93.71499633789062, 34.734683990478516], [768, 550, -74, 47.400001525878906, 79, 16.799999237060547, 0.07999999821186066, 0.9800000190734863, 2, 0.07999999821186066, 0.003000000026077032, 0.0020000000949949026, 0.003000000026077032, 11.100000381469727, 1.399999976158142, 170, 0.0, 278, 9.069000244140625, 6.755000114440918, 6, 112748, '2022-04-16 12:12:40', -85.25, 30.989999771118164, -84.97000122070312, 31.139999389648438, -85.125, 31.052263259887695], [19, 0, 0, 10.199999809265137, 241, 34.900001525878906, 0.0, 0.4300000071525574, 0, 0.0, 0.0010000000474974513, 0.0, 0.0, 5.599999904632568, 0.8999999761581421, 0, 0.0, 132, 15.03600025177002, 39.154998779296875, 0, 112144, '2022-04-16 09:58:38', -82.62000274658203, 36.599998474121094, -82.48999786376953, 36.709999084472656, -82.55500030517578, 36.66690444946289], [1836, 1451, -5, 38.20000076293945, 59, 19.100000381469727, 0.2199999988079071, 1.3799999952316284, 2, 0.5099999904632568, 0.004000000189989805, 0.003000000026077032, 0.003000000026077032, 11.199999809265137, 1.7000000476837158, 506, 0.0, 208, 4.265999794006348, 3.2790000438690186, 8, 115480, '2022-04-16 21:54:38', -91.86000061035156, 31.969999313354492, -91.68000030517578, 32.099998474121094, -91.76499938964844, 32.0463752746582], [29, 0, -999, 8.300000190734863, 196, 32.70000076293945, 0.0, 0.4000000059604645, 0, 0.0, 0.0010000000474974513, 0.0010000000474974513, 0.0010000000474974513, 4.800000190734863, 0.8999999761581421, 0, 0.0, 169, 9.41100025177002, 5.998000144958496, 0, 112144, '2022-04-16 09:42:36', -82.88999938964844, 36.630001068115234, -82.70999908447266, 36.77000045776367, -82.79499816894531, 36.694908142089844], [22, 0, 0, 8.699999809265137, 247, 35.29999923706055, 0.0, 0.4300000071525574, 0, 0.0, 0.0010000000474974513, 0.0, 0.0020000000949949026, 5.5, 0.8999999761581421, 0, 0.0, 189, 10.336000442504883, 3.2260000705718994, 0, 112144, '2022-04-16 09:56:36', -82.69000244140625, 36.599998474121094, -82.52999877929688, 36.72999954223633, -82.61499786376953, 36.66690444946289], [1594, 1028, -118, 58.0, 215, 42.0, 0.4000000059604645, 1.7200000286102295, 12, 0.6399999856948853, 0.012000000104308128, 0.009999999776482582, 0.006000000052154064, 10.800000190734863, 1.5, 463, 0.0, 326, 13.5649995803833, 1.5700000524520874, 39, 110129, '2022-04-16 02:26:40', -91.48999786376953, 35.369998931884766, -91.25, 35.54999923706055, -91.36499786376953, 35.44876480102539], [777, 551, -73, 47.5, 79, 16.799999237060547, 0.09000000357627869, 0.8399999737739563, 2, 0.07999999821186066, 0.003000000026077032, 0.0020000000949949026, 0.0020000000949949026, 11.100000381469727, 1.399999976158142, 171, 0.0, 246, 9.878000259399414, 6.5229997634887695, 7, 112748, '2022-04-16 12:10:41', -85.23999786376953, 31.0, -84.9800033569336, 31.139999389648438, -85.1050033569336, 31.08026695251465], [1592, 10, 0, 51.599998474121094, 151, 6.400000095367432, 0.0, 0.5400000214576721, 0, 0.019999999552965164, 0.007000000216066837, 0.003000000026077032, 0.0020000000949949026, 10.199999809265137, 1.5, 442, 0.0, 50, 5.730999946594238, 4.414000034332275, 6, 113205, '2022-04-16 14:22:40', -94.88999938964844, 35.939998626708984, -94.83000183105469, 36.0099983215332, -94.8550033569336, 35.98082733154297], [207, 0, 0, 21.5, 342, 37.0, 0.0, 0.6499999761581421, 1, 0.05999999865889549, 0.008999999612569809, 0.004999999888241291, 0.004000000189989805, 7.0, 1.0, 30, 0.0, 589, 13.6850004196167, -2.4509999752044678, 0, 110971, '2022-04-16 05:54:42', -86.05999755859375, 35.15999984741211, -85.72000122070312, 35.4900016784668, -85.88500213623047, 35.322750091552734], [1555, 1069, -116, 55.79999923706055, 205, 42.0, 0.2800000011920929, 1.5, 12, 0.6399999856948853, 0.013000000268220901, 0.009999999776482582, 0.006000000052154064, 10.699999809265137, 1.399999976158142, 450, 3.4000000953674316, 253, 12.890000343322754, 2.8340001106262207, 28, 110129, '2022-04-16 02:24:37', -91.54000091552734, 35.38999938964844, -91.33000183105469, 35.560001373291016, -91.42500305175781, 35.4627685546875], [1529, 930, -17, 43.599998474121094, 55, 18.0, 0.6800000071525574, 1.8600000143051147, 20, 0.9399999976158142, 0.007000000216066837, 0.006000000052154064, 0.004999999888241291, 10.399999618530273, 1.7000000476837158, 318, 0.0, 322, 2.928999900817871, 13.524999618530273, 44, 113168, '2022-04-16 13:52:40', -93.5999984741211, 34.47999954223633, -93.43000030517578, 34.7599983215332, -93.5250015258789, 34.6226692199707], [1180, 369, -64, 42.20000076293945, 27, 8.0, 0.17000000178813934, 1.0499999523162842, 1, 0.07000000029802322, 0.003000000026077032, 0.0020000000949949026, 0.0020000000949949026, 11.100000381469727, 1.899999976158142, 232, 0.0, 65, 9.628999710083008, -2.7760000228881836, 7, 114668, '2022-04-16 19:18:37', -88.0, 32.22999954223633, -87.91999816894531, 32.310001373291016, -87.95500183105469, 32.27040100097656], [498, 83, -999, 38.599998474121094, 57, 21.0, 0.17000000178813934, 2.0899999141693115, 1, 0.03999999910593033, 0.004000000189989805, 0.003000000026077032, 0.003000000026077032, 9.199999809265137, 1.2000000476837158, 16, 0.0, 48, 9.467000007629395, -0.6209999918937683, 4, 109857, '2022-04-16 01:42:40', -88.08000183105469, 32.75, -88.0199966430664, 32.83000183105469, -88.05500030517578, 32.78845977783203], [447, 75, -999, 36.400001525878906, 61, 21.100000381469727, 0.17000000178813934, 2.0899999141693115, 0, 0.03999999910593033, 0.004000000189989805, 0.003000000026077032, 0.004000000189989805, 9.199999809265137, 1.2000000476837158, 11, 0.0, 134, 9.88599967956543, 0.21899999678134918, 3, 109857, '2022-04-16 01:44:35', -88.11000061035156, 32.7400016784668, -87.94999694824219, 32.84000015258789, -88.0250015258789, 32.80246353149414], [2272, 1547, -21, 50.099998474121094, 103, 16.200000762939453, 0.5199999809265137, 2.0, 44, 0.5400000214576721, 0.008999999612569809, 0.006000000052154064, 0.004999999888241291, 10.600000381469727, 1.600000023841858, 600, 0.0, 423, 10.493000030517578, 3.809000015258789, 71, 111302, '2022-04-16 07:46:42', -95.2300033569336, 35.27000045776367, -94.88999938964844, 35.5, -95.1449966430664, 35.37875747680664], [190, 0, 0, 27.299999237060547, 296, 40.0, 0.0, 0.38999998569488525, 0, 0.0, 0.0020000000949949026, 0.0020000000949949026, 0.003000000026077032, 8.899999618530273, 1.2000000476837158, 30, 0.0, 46, 13.42199993133545, -2.694999933242798, 1, 111160, '2022-04-16 06:42:38', -86.55000305175781, 36.130001068115234, -86.47000122070312, 36.20000076293945, -86.51499938964844, 36.162845611572266], [1590, 1028, -119, 58.0, 215, 42.0, 0.4000000059604645, 1.7200000286102295, 12, 0.47999998927116394, 0.010999999940395355, 0.009999999776482582, 0.006000000052154064, 10.800000190734863, 1.5, 461, 0.0, 225, 13.64799976348877, 1.496999979019165, 39, 110129, '2022-04-16 02:28:39', -91.45999908447266, 35.380001068115234, -91.27999877929688, 35.540000915527344, -91.36499786376953, 35.4627685546875], [1186, 378, -66, 43.20000076293945, 30, 8.399999618530273, 0.17000000178813934, 1.0499999523162842, 2, 0.07000000029802322, 0.003000000026077032, 0.0020000000949949026, 0.0020000000949949026, 11.100000381469727, 1.899999976158142, 233, 0.0, 77, 10.157999992370605, -2.7130000591278076, 7, 114668, '2022-04-16 19:16:39', -88.02999877929688, 32.22999954223633, -87.94000244140625, 32.310001373291016, -87.98500061035156, 32.27040100097656], [2579, 1705, -10, 52.20000076293945, 58, 16.700000762939453, 0.4399999976158142, 1.9199999570846558, 10, 0.6899999976158142, 0.004999999888241291, 0.004000000189989805, 0.003000000026077032, 11.199999809265137, 1.899999976158142, 577, 0.0, 43, 2.3910000324249268, 10.97599983215332, 34, 116079, '2022-04-16 23:48:39', -88.88999938964844, 30.600000381469727, -88.83000183105469, 30.65999984741211, -88.8550033569336, 30.618213653564453], [1103, 372, -48, 40.0, 6, 4.400000095367432, 0.18000000715255737, 1.440000057220459, 1, 0.10999999940395355, 0.004000000189989805, 0.003000000026077032, 0.003000000026077032, 11.100000381469727, 1.7999999523162842, 214, 0.0, 213, 9.090999603271484, 1.0260000228881836, 6, 114559, '2022-04-16 18:16:40', -88.02999877929688, 32.470001220703125, -87.86000061035156, 32.630001068115234, -87.93499755859375, 32.55043411254883], [1712, 1033, -34, 44.900001525878906, 78, 17.399999618530273, 0.5199999809265137, 1.809999942779541, 16, 0.6200000047683716, 0.008999999612569809, 0.007000000216066837, 0.004000000189989805, 10.199999809265137, 1.7000000476837158, 345, 0.0, 251, 6.798999786376953, 2.878000020980835, 32, 113168, '2022-04-16 13:32:37', -93.80999755859375, 34.61000061035156, -93.62999725341797, 34.84000015258789, -93.71499633789062, 34.72068405151367], [1104, 372, -47, 40.400001525878906, 5, 4.5, 0.1599999964237213, 1.440000057220459, 1, 0.10999999940395355, 0.004000000189989805, 0.003000000026077032, 0.003000000026077032, 11.100000381469727, 1.7999999523162842, 212, 0.0, 223, 8.333000183105469, 1.2070000171661377, 5, 114559, '2022-04-16 18:20:40', -88.01000213623047, 32.459999084472656, -87.81999969482422, 32.619998931884766, -87.91500091552734, 32.536434173583984], [1104, 373, -47, 40.400001525878906, 6, 4.5, 0.1599999964237213, 1.440000057220459, 1, 0.10999999940395355, 0.004000000189989805, 0.003000000026077032, 0.003000000026077032, 11.100000381469727, 1.7999999523162842, 213, 0.0, 219, 9.843999862670898, 1.5440000295639038, 5, 114559, '2022-04-16 18:18:38', -88.01000213623047, 32.459999084472656, -87.83000183105469, 32.619998931884766, -87.90499877929688, 32.55043411254883], [2384, 1839, -24, 50.599998474121094, 125, 20.0, 1.0700000524520874, 3.0, 45, 0.4699999988079071, 0.007000000216066837, 0.004000000189989805, 0.007000000216066837, 10.600000381469727, 1.7000000476837158, 629, 1.0, 490, 9.942999839782715, 3.9560000896453857, 94, 111302, '2022-04-16 08:08:40', -95.08999633789062, 35.119998931884766, -94.79000091552734, 35.40999984741211, -94.94499969482422, 35.266746520996094], [2232, 1869, -3, 45.400001525878906, 79, 17.100000381469727, 0.1899999976158142, 1.2100000381469727, 4, 0.5099999904632568, 0.003000000026077032, 0.003000000026077032, 0.003000000026077032, 11.199999809265137, 1.7000000476837158, 589, 0.0, 82, 4.843999862670898, 2.694999933242798, 13, 115480, '2022-04-16 22:06:40', -91.80000305175781, 31.969999313354492, -91.70999908447266, 32.060001373291016, -91.75499725341797, 32.01837158203125], [682, 14, 0, 38.70000076293945, 271, 39.70000076293945, 0.03999999910593033, 0.9800000190734863, 1, 0.05000000074505806, 0.00800000037997961, 0.004000000189989805, 0.006000000052154064, 11.699999809265137, 1.5, 186, 0.0, 140, 13.654999732971191, -3.0810000896453857, 2, 111075, '2022-04-16 06:26:38', -87.08000183105469, 33.5099983215332, -86.91999816894531, 33.599998474121094, -86.99500274658203, 33.55854797363281], [18, 0, 0, 10.5, 240, 34.79999923706055, 0.0, 0.41999998688697815, 0, 0.0, 0.0010000000474974513, 0.0, 0.0010000000474974513, 5.599999904632568, 0.8999999761581421, 0, 0.0, 138, 10.708000183105469, 4.317999839782715, 0, 112144, '2022-04-16 10:00:38', -82.5999984741211, 36.59000015258789, -82.47000122070312, 36.709999084472656, -82.53500366210938, 36.66690444946289], [1553, 911, -24, 43.20000076293945, 58, 18.399999618530273, 0.6399999856948853, 1.8600000143051147, 20, 0.9399999976158142, 0.008999999612569809, 0.007000000216066837, 0.004000000189989805, 10.300000190734863, 1.7000000476837158, 321, 1.7000000476837158, 235, 11.043000221252441, 4.551000118255615, 40, 113168, '2022-04-16 13:48:35', -93.63999938964844, 34.56999969482422, -93.5, 34.77000045776367, -93.55500030517578, 34.67867660522461], [1092, 372, -49, 39.0, 9, 4.300000190734863, 0.1899999976158142, 1.1699999570846558, 2, 0.10999999940395355, 0.004000000189989805, 0.003000000026077032, 0.003000000026077032, 11.100000381469727, 1.7999999523162842, 218, 0.0, 224, 8.91100025177002, -2.6040000915527344, 6, 114559, '2022-04-16 18:06:38', -88.0999984741211, 32.470001220703125, -87.91000366210938, 32.63999938964844, -88.00499725341797, 32.56443405151367], [225, 0, 0, 24.299999237060547, 332, 36.900001525878906, 0.0, 0.5600000023841858, 3, 0.05999999865889549, 0.00800000037997961, 0.004999999888241291, 0.006000000052154064, 7.699999809265137, 1.100000023841858, 47, 0.0, 444, 13.458000183105469, -3.171999931335449, 0, 110971, '2022-04-16 05:46:39', -86.18000030517578, 35.08000183105469, -85.95999908447266, 35.369998931884766, -86.07499694824219, 35.22473907470703], [497, 0, -4, 31.5, 206, 25.799999237060547, 0.0, 0.3799999952316284, 0, 0.0, 0.004999999888241291, 0.004000000189989805, 0.0020000000949949026, 9.300000190734863, 1.2999999523162842, 69, 0.0, 65, 11.142999649047852, 39.297000885009766, 1, 112741, '2022-04-16 11:38:42', -86.08000183105469, 34.7599983215332, -85.9800033569336, 34.84000015258789, -86.03500366210938, 34.804691314697266], [2399, 1801, -24, 49.79999923706055, 119, 20.200000762939453, 0.699999988079071, 2.609999895095825, 42, 0.5400000214576721, 0.007000000216066837, 0.004999999888241291, 0.004999999888241291, 10.600000381469727, 1.7000000476837158, 636, 0.0, 398, 8.123000144958496, 1.3910000324249268, 80, 111302, '2022-04-16 08:02:40', -95.12999725341797, 35.16999816894531, -94.91999816894531, 35.43000030517578, -95.0250015258789, 35.30875015258789], [1676, 966, -118, 59.400001525878906, 233, 42.0, 0.4399999976158142, 1.659999966621399, 4, 0.4099999964237213, 0.00800000037997961, 0.006000000052154064, 0.003000000026077032, 10.899999618530273, 1.5, 488, 0.0, 238, 14.715999603271484, 0.35600000619888306, 42, 110129, '2022-04-16 02:38:42', -91.36000061035156, 35.380001068115234, -91.16000366210938, 35.529998779296875, -91.23500061035156, 35.476768493652344]]
```

### sample cudf.DataFrame

```py
import cudf

df = cudf.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df["VALIDTIME"] = cudf.to_datetime(df["VALIDTIME"])
df.set_index(["VALIDTIME", "ID"]).sort_index(level="VALIDTIME")
```

The main objective here is to identify the observed lat/lon of a storm, and then fit that into the bounding box's known grid.

the `BoundingBox.__calculate_step` `method` uses [nvector](https://github.com/pbrod/nvector) to determine grid distance.  Generally the idea here is to take the `MOTION_EAST` and `MOTION_SOUTH` overtime to predict its next location in the grid.

### `app/__main__.py`

`python -m app`

````py
from pathlib import Path
from contextlib import contextmanager
from typing import Iterable, Generator
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

import cudf
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np
import nvector as nv
from numpy.typing import NDArray


class CUDArray(NDArray):
    def get(self) -> np.ndarray:
        ...


@contextmanager
def gpu_session(files: Iterable[Path]) -> Generator[cudf.DataFrame, None, None]:
    """
    context manager to remove the dataframe from the gpu menory
    """
    try:
        gdf = cudf.read_parquet(files).set_index(["VALIDTIME", "ID"]).sort_index(level="VALIDTIME")
        yield gdf
    finally:
        del gdf


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class BoundingBox:
    """
    Nominatim API
    Nominatim API returns a boundingbox property of the form:

    south Latitude, north Latitude, west Longitude, east Longitude
    For example, Greater London in JSON format:

    "boundingbox":["51.2867602","51.6918741","-0.5103751","0.3340155"]
    """

    south: float
    north: float
    east: float
    west: float
    shape: tuple[int, int]
    frame_e: nv.FrameE = field(repr=False, default=nv.FrameE(name="WGS84"))

    @property
    def latitudes(self) -> CUDArray:
        _, y_num = self.shape
        return cp.linspace(
            self.south,  # south lat
            self.north,  # north lat
            y_num,  # points in between
            dtype=cp.float32,
        )

    @property
    def longitudes(self) -> CUDArray:
        x_num, _ = self.shape
        return cp.linspace(
            self.west,  # west lon
            self.east,  # east lon
            x_num,  # points in between
            dtype=cp.float32,
        )

    @property
    def matrix(self) -> CUDArray:
        return cp.array(cp.meshgrid(self.latitudes, self.longitudes), dtype=cp.float32).T

    @property
    def latrange(self) -> tuple[float, float]:
        return self.north, self.south

    @property
    def lonrange(self) -> tuple[float, float]:
        return self.west, self.east

    @property
    def y_dist(self) -> CUDArray:

        return self.__calculate_step(
            self.longitudes,
            self.latrange,
            len(self.latitudes),
        )

    @property
    def x_dist(self) -> CUDArray:

        return self.__calculate_step(
            self.latitudes,
            self.lonrange,
            len(self.longitudes),
        )

    def __calculate_step(self, target: CUDArray, step_range: tuple[float, float], count: int) -> CUDArray:
        """
        calculates the geometric distance within the bounding box

        ```
        array_west, array_east = np.array(list([bbox.lonrange]) * len(bbox.latitudes)).T

        ecef_west = bbox.frame_e.GeoPoint(bbox.latitudes.get(), array_west, degrees=True).to_ecef_vector()

        ecef_east = bbox.frame_e.GeoPoint(bbox.latitudes.get(), array_east, degrees=True).to_ecef_vector()

        ecef_delta = ecef_east - ecef_west

        return cp.array(ecef_delta.length) / len(bbox.longitudes)
        ```
        """

        array_a, array_b = np.array([[step_range]] * len(target)).T

        ecef_a = self.frame_e.GeoPoint(target.get(), array_a, degrees=True).to_ecef_vector()

        ecef_b = self.frame_e.GeoPoint(target.get(), array_b, degrees=True).to_ecef_vector()

        ecef_delta = ecef_a - ecef_b

        return cp.array(ecef_delta.length) / count


def assert_bbox(south: float, north: float, west: float, east: float, *, shape: tuple[float, float]) -> BoundingBox:
    bbox = BoundingBox(south, north, west, east, shape=shape)
    assert (
        (bbox.latitudes.min() == south)
        & (bbox.latitudes.max() == north)
        & (bbox.longitudes.min() == west)
        & (bbox.longitudes.max() == east)
    )
    assert shape == (*bbox.y_dist.shape, *bbox.x_dist.shape)
    assert cp.array(cp.meshgrid(bbox.x_dist, bbox.y_dist)).T.shape == bbox.matrix.shape
    return bbox


def fit2grid(values: CUDArray, target: CUDArray) -> CUDArray:
    return target[cp.argmin(abs(target - values[:, cp.newaxis]), axis=1)]


def main(files: tuple[Path, ...]):
    bbox = assert_bbox(20.005, 54.995, -129.995, -60.005, shape=(7000, 2500))
    with gpu_session(files) as gdf:
        grid_lat = fit2grid(gdf["Y"].values, bbox.latitudes)
        grid_lon = fit2grid(gdf["X"].values, bbox.longitudes)
        assert cp.allclose(cp.array((grid_lon, grid_lat)).T, gdf[["X", "Y"]].to_cupy(), rtol=0.001)
        gdf["X"] = grid_lon
        gdf["Y"] = grid_lat

        df = gdf.to_pandas()

    print(
        f"""\
    starting from: {min(df.index.unique('VALIDTIME'))}
    ending at: {max(df.index.unique('VALIDTIME'))}
    total values: {df.size}
    unique storms: {df.index.unique("ID").size}\
    """
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ps_data = Path.cwd() / "data-bucket"
    all_files = tuple(ps_data.rglob("*.pq"))
    assert len(all_files) == 8612
    main(all_files[: len(all_files) // 50])
````

```
    starting from: 2022-03-05 07:48:39
    ending at: 2022-06-05 23:58:37
    total values: 2291166
    unique storms: 54866
```